# Custom Confirmation dialog doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have created custom dialogs like Alert and ConfirmDialog with Bootstrap and Jquery.

Here is sample : http://jsfiddle.net/eb71eaya/

Problem - in the callback I make an ajax call, and if it returns true - I show an alert with status **success** else - **error**. But this alert doesn't show while request makes delete. (In the example I don't make an ajax request, just show alert, but that also doesn't work.)

```
    function getEsrbAlertDialog(title, msg, callBack, obj) {
    var esrbAlertDialog = $('#esrb-dialog');
    if (esrbAlertDialog.length == 0) {
        esrbAlertDialog = getEsrbDialog(title, msg);
    } else {
        $('.modal-title', esrbAlertDialog).html(title);
        $('.modal-body', esrbAlertDialog).html(msg);
    }

    $('.modal-footer div', esrbAlertDialog).empty();
    $('.modal-footer div', esrbAlertDialog).append('<button class="btn btn-primary pull-right close-btn">Close</button>');

    $('.close-btn', esrbAlertDialog).unbind('click').click(function () {
        if (typeof callBack === "function") {
            todo = callBack(obj);
        }
        esrbAlertDialog.modal('hide');
    });

    return esrbAlertDialog;
};
```

I want to execute callback when confirmation dialog become closed.

---

UPDATE : I understand logic like this : When user click on "Ok"-button, dialog must be closed. And when it is already closed then fire event 'hidden.bs.modal' which must execute callBack. But CallBack executes before confirm dialog finish hiding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
esrbConfirmationDialog.modal('hide');
```

Is hiding the second dialog.

---

EDIT:
Both dialogs use the same div as there reference:

```
var esrbAlertDialog = $('#esrb-dialog');
```

Create seperate dialogs one for the alert and one for confirmation.

Comment: yes, this makes sense. But what updates should I add to close confirmDialog and then open alert?

Comment: when my callBack wouldn't have any custom dialog, then confirm dialog will never be closed

Comment: it's very specific case. For example my callBack wouldn't contain my custom dialog - then first confirm dialog will be displayed until user click "Close" btn. http://jsfiddle.net/eb71eaya/2/

Comment: when in callBack we wouldn't use custom Dialog, then logic that exists is good

Comment: So you want to hide the confirm after the user chooses an option ? :
http://jsfiddle.net/eb71eaya/3/

If you want to close the confirm dialog after u executed something in the callback then you have to pass the dialog in the callback:
http://jsfiddle.net/eb71eaya/4/

Comment: Yes, i want to close confirm dialog when user chooses some option. After this execute callBack. But i don't know how to handle 2 cases : when callback contains another custom dialog and when not.

Comment: Check out these fiddles:
jsfiddle.net/eb71eaya/3
jsfiddle.net/eb71eaya/4 

Dont they do what you want ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66590/discussion-between-demo-and-jeroen).

Answer (score 0):

Just replace this.Alert function to below code, i.e. just add e.preventDefault();

```
this.Alert = function (dialogMsg, callBack, obj) {   

    var dlg = getEsrbAlertDialog('Alert', dialogMsg, callBack, obj);   
       e.preventDefault();
    dlg.modal('show');
};
```